Web2Py Face Recognition with OpenCV
How can we implement this OpenCV into Web2Py framework but use it as a button that opens up a video in html component that read your face and return true or false if its validated?
The main problem is that its outputting the video feed ínto a separate windows pop up and not into html component.
The validation faces are in a directory located inside
url
C:/web2py/applications/FaceCheck/static/images/users/user1.jpg
C:/web2py/applications/FaceCheck/static/images/users/user2.jpg
I currently am using this but its outputting it into a different pop windows with my system and not html code.
Web2py CODE
VIEW
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

{{block header}}
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid background" style="background-color: #333; color:white; padding:30px;word-wrap:break-word;">
  <div class="container center">
    <h1 class="display-5">/{{=request.application}}/{{=request.controller}}/{{=request.function}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
{{end}}

<div class="row">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
        <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
        <img src="">
        {{=rgb_frame}}
        <br>
        {{=video_capture}}
        

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div width="640px" height="480px" style="display:inline-block">
    <h1>Image</h1>
    <img id="img" src="">
  </div>

</div>

Controller
 def index():
    import face_recognition
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    # This is a demo of running face recognition on live video from your webcam. It's a little more complicated than the
    # other example, but it includes some basic performance tweaks to make things run a lot faster:
    #   1. Process each video frame at 1/4 resolution (though still display it at full resolution)
    #   2. Only detect faces in every other frame of video.

    # PLEASE NOTE: This example requires OpenCV (the `cv2` library) to be installed only to read from your webcam.
    # OpenCV is *not* required to use the face_recognition library. It's only required if you want to run this
    # specific demo. If you have trouble installing it, try any of the other demos that don't require it instead.

    # Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

    # Find OpenCV version
    (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')


    fps = video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print("Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : {0}".format(fps))
 
    # Number of frames to capture
    num_frames = 120
 
    print("Capturing {0} frames".format(fps))

    print('Start!')
    print('\n')

    # Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
    ricardo_velez_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/web2py/applications/FaceCheck/static/images/users/user1.jpg")
    ricardo_velez_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(user1_image)[0]

    # Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
    rosangerli_de_jesus_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("C:/web2py/applications/FaceCheck/static/images/users/user2.jpg")
    rosangerli_de_jesus_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(user2_image)[0]

    # Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
    known_face_encodings = [
        user1_face_encoding,
        user2_face_encoding
    ]
    known_face_names = [
        "User1",
        "User2"
    ]

    # Initialize some variables
    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    face_names = []
    process_this_frame = True

    while True:
        # Grab a single frame of video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        #rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
        rgb_frame = np.ascontiguousarray(frame[:, :, ::-1])

        # Find all the faces and face enqcodings in the frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

        # Loop through each face in this frame of video
        for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

            name = "Unknown"

            # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
            # if True in matches:
            #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
            #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        # Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


    # Release handle to the webcam
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return locals()

